# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar add

Tags: python, numpy

I created this cost function.

```
xTrain = numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50,55,70])
yTrain = numpy.array([200,230,400,300,280,250,50])

def costFunction(w,b):
    global xTrain
    global yTrain
    a = 0

    for i in range(len(yTrain)):
        a += ((yTrain[i] - (w*xTrain[i]+b)))**2
    
    a /=  2*len(yTrain)
    return a

print(costFunction(500,-4100))
```

I am getting an overflow error in the line `a += ((yTrain[i] - (w*xTrain[i]+b)))**2`.

As far as I know python doesn't have strict memory sizes for datatypes like C so it shouldn't overflow. What am I doing wrong? is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you add error traceback to the question?

Comment: Note that your calculations can be vectorised, which is supposed to be done when you work with `numpy`: `((yTrain - w * xTrain - b) ** 2).sum() / 2 / yTrain.shape[0]`

Comment: Elements of your numpy arrays are not  python integers, but numpy ones, `np.int32` or `np.int64`

Comment: @MariaK, errors give a traceback, but warnings don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know python doesn't have strict memory sizes for datatypes like C so it shouldn't overflow. What am I doing wrong? is there a way to fix it?

Python doesn't have a fixed size for `int`s, but it does for floats, and NumPy has fixed sizes for both.

Your integers start as `np.int64`s with a maximum size of `9223372036854775807`.

```py
import numpy as np
xTrain = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55, 70])
yTrain = np.array([200, 230, 400, 300, 280, 250, 50])
type(xTrain[0])  # <class 'numpy.int64'>
np.iinfo(xTrain.dtype).max  # 9223372036854775807
```

If your overflow is happening in your `for` loop, during which `a` remains an integer, you can ensure that it doesn't become a NumPy integer by making the arrays Python integers. Then the integer result will not by subject to the size limit of NumPy ints.

```py
xTrain = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55, 70], dtype=object)
yTrain = np.array([200, 230, 400, 300, 280, 250, 50], dtype=object)
type(xTrain[0])  # <class 'int'>
```

This will make your program much slower, though, because arithmetic with Python integers is much slower than arithmetic with NumPy integers.

Then again, you're not taking advantage of any vectorized operations now, so you could also just leave them as lists of Python integers.

Another option is to use floats from the outset.

```py
xTrain = numpy.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 55, 70], dtype=float)
yTrain = numpy.array([200, 230, 400, 300, 280, 250, 50], dtype=float)
type(xTrain[0])  # <class 'numpy.float64'>
np.finfo(xTrain.dtype).max  # 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

You may lose a bit of precision during the integer part of the calculation, but since the result is a float anyway, it probably won't matter. These would be much faster.

---

Aside:
It doesn't seem necessary here, but if you want to have floating point types that don't overflow, you can use `mpmath`.

```
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 30  # set precision
xTrain = numpy.array([mp.mpf(el) for el in [10,20,30,40,50,55,70]])
yTrain = numpy.array([mp.mpf(el) for el in [200,230,400,300,280,250,50]])
```